# Move all users documents into a subfolder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that will move all my users documents, currently in "\server\share\%username%" to "\server\share\%username%\Documents".
 It will also check to see if the documents folder exists and if not it will create it.

To test this works I have broken the script up to test each section and replaced the actual command with a Write-Host, this section should test to see if the documents folder exists.

when I run it and check the users home folders that are highlighted yellow, some user have a documents folder and some dont, but it should only highlight the ones that dont have a documents folder yellow.

```
$userhomes = Get-ChildItem "D:\" | where {$_.Attributes -like '*Directory*'}
foreach($userhome in $userhomes) {
$exclude = "Documents"
$movesource = "D:\" + $userhome.Name
$movedest = "D:\"+ $userhome.Name +"\Documents"
$autodest = "D:\"+ $userhome.Name +"\Documents"+"\Autorecovery"
$docexists = Test-Path $movedest
$autoexists = Test-Path $autodest
$Search = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk"
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $Search

$users | % {

# Check if Documents folder already exists
If ($docexists -eq $false)
    {
# Create the Documents folder
# Get-Item -path $movesource | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$movesource\Documents"
    Write-Host Documents folder does not exists for ($_.SamAccountName) -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
else
{
    Write-Host Documents folder already exists for ($_.SamAccountName) -ForegroundColor Red
}
}
}
```

After the documents folder has been created I want to create another folder and set the attributes to Hidden if the folder does not exist already.

```
# Check if Autorecovery folder already exists
If ($autoexists -eq $false)
{ 
    # Create the Autorecovery folder and set attributes
    Get-Item -path $movesource | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$movesource\Documents\Autorecovery" | %{$_.Attributes="hidden"}
    Write-Host Documents and Autorecovery folder for ($_.SamAccountName) created -ForegroundColor Green
}
 else
{
 Write-Host Autorecovery folder already exists for ($_.SamAccountName) -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Once this is sorted I then want to check that the folder path "\\server\share\%username%\documents" folder exists.
 If it does I then want to move all the documents from the "%username%" folder to the "Documents" folder and finally change the AD home folder path to point to the new location.

```
# Move Documents to new location
If ($docexists = $true)
{
Get-Childitem -path $movesource -exclude $exclude | Move-Item -Dest $movedest

    # Set user new home folder path
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $Search | Foreach-Object{

    $sam = $_.SamAccountName
    Set-ADuser -Identity $_ -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory "\\server\share\$sam\Documents"
}
else
{
Write-Host Documents folder does not exist for ($_.SamAccountName) -ForegroundColor Red
}
}
}
```

Comment: You've included a lot of detail about what your script does (which is great!), but haven't made it very clear what doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry James
The issue I have is that the script is saying that the users have a documents folder when they dont and it is also saying that users dont have a documents folder when they do have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only problem I am seeing you list is in the first portion when it should only be coloring users yellow if they do not have a documents folder.  The issue here would seem to be your loop nesting.  your `$users` loop is inside of your `$userhomes` loop, so right now for each user home directory you are setting all of your variables, then getting a collection of all users in the domain, then looping through that collection and populating each of them with the variable that was set for that step of the `$userhomes` loop, which is unrelated to the user that is being worked on in the `$users` loop.  The solution here is just to eliminate `$users` loop and just output the names of the folders rather than the users samaccountname, like I have below, which should work if the names of their home drives reflect their account names. if not you could always do a lookup based on the homedirectory property in AD but you'll need to parse your existing filename into the network name.

```
$userhomes = Get-ChildItem "D:\" | where {$_.Attributes -like '*Directory*'}
foreach($userhome in $userhomes) {
$exclude = "Documents"
$movesource = "D:\" + $userhome.Name
$movedest = "D:\"+ $userhome.Name +"\Documents"
$autodest = "D:\"+ $userhome.Name +"\Documents"+"\Autorecovery"
$docexists = Test-Path $movedest
$autoexists = Test-Path $autodest


# Check if Documents folder already exists
If ($docexists -eq $false)
{
# Create the Documents folder
# Get-Item -path $movesource | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$movesource\Documents"
Write-Host "Documents folder does not exists for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Yellow"
}
else
{
Write-Host "Documents folder already exists for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Red"
}
}
```

If none of that will work for you you could also loop through the collection of users and calculate the home drive for them.  You just need to be relating the two somehow, which you are currently not doing in your nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

This should sort it for you, it checks and moves any user folders in the D: drive. Then goes through AD after and updates the Home Folders.

```
$userhomes = Get-ChildItem "D:\" | where {$_.Attributes -like '*Directory*'}
foreach($userhome in $userhomes) {
    $movesource = "D:\" + $userhome.Name
    $movedest = "$movesource\Documents"
    $autodest = "$movedest\Autorecovery"
    $exclude = "Documents"

    # Check if Documents folder already exists
    If (Test-Path $movedest)
    {
        Write-Host Documents folder already exists for ($_.SamAccountName) -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else
    {
        # Create the Documents folder
        # New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $movedest
        Write-Host Documents folder does not exists for ($_.SamAccountName) -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

    # Check if Autorecovery folder already exists
    If (Test-Path $autodest)
    {
     Write-Host Autorecovery folder already exists for ($_.SamAccountName) -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else
    { 
        # Create the Autorecovery folder and set attributes
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $autodest | %{$_.Attributes="hidden"}
        Write-Host Documents and Autorecovery folder for ($_.SamAccountName) created -ForegroundColor Green
    }

    # Move Documents to new location
    if (Test-Path $movedest)
    {
        Get-Childitem -path $movesource -exclude $exclude | Move-Item -Dest $movedest
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Host Documents folder does not exist for ($_.SamAccountName) -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

# Set user new home folder path
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $Search | Foreach-Object{
    $sam = $_.SamAccountName
    Set-ADuser -Identity $_ -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory "\\server\share\$sam\Documents"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recomendations, these may work but the problem I have with these is that the ($_.SamAccountName) in the write-host has nothing to input.
so the write-host output says " Documents folder already exists for        ", so without the account name I have no way of checking the results.

Comment: Try this: `Write-Host "Documents folder already exists for $($_.SamAccountName)" -ForegroundColor Red`

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to say a big thanks for all the help, here is my completed script.
At any stage it informs me what's going on and if there are any issues.

```
$userhomes = Get-ChildItem "D:\" | where {$_.Attributes -like '*Directory*'}
foreach($userhome in $userhomes) {
$exclude = "Documents"
$movesource = "D:\" + $userhome.Name
$movedest = "D:\"+ $userhome.Name +"\Documents"
$autodest = "D:\"+ $userhome.Name +"\Documents"+"\Autorecovery"
$testpath = "D:\"+ $userhome.Name +"\Desktop"
$Search = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk"
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $Search

# Test if Documents folder exists, create folder if it doesnt exist
If (Test-Path $movedest)
{
Write-Host Documents folder exists for $($userhome)

# Test if Autorecovery folder exists, create folder if it doesnt exist
If (Test-Path $autodest)
{
Write-Host Autorecovery folder exist for $($userhome)

    # Move Documents to new location
    If (Test-Path $testpath)
    {
    Get-Childitem -path $movesource -exclude $exclude | Move-Item -Dest $movedest
    Get-ChildItem -Path  $movesource -Exclude "Documents" | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} |Remove-Item -Recurse -force 
    Write-Host Documents being moved for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Yellow


    }
    else
    {
    Write-Host Documents already moved for $($userhome)
    }

}    
else
{
# Create the Autorecovery folder and set hidden attribute
Get-Item -path $movesource | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$movesource\Documents\Autorecovery" | %{$_.Attributes="hidden"}
Write-Host Autorecovery folder being created for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Green

    # Move Documents to new location
    If (Test-Path $testpath)
    {
    Get-Childitem -path $movesource -exclude $exclude | Move-Item -Dest $movedest
    Get-ChildItem -Path  $movesource -Exclude "Documents" | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} |Remove-Item -Recurse -force 
    Write-Host Documents being moved for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Yellow


    }
    else
    {
    Write-Host Documents already moved for $($userhome)
    }

}

}
else
{
# Create the Documents folder
Get-Item -path $movesource | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$movesource\Documents"
Write-Host Documents folder being created for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Green

# Check that Documents folder now exists
If (Test-Path $movedest)
{
Write-Host Documents folder now exists for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Magenta
Get-Item -path $movesource | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$movesource\Documents\Autorecovery" | %{$_.Attributes="hidden"}

    # Test if Autorecovery folder now exists
    If (Test-Path $autodest)
    {
    Write-Host Autorecovery folder Created for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Green

        # Move Documents to new location
        If (Test-Path $testpath)
        {
        Get-Childitem -path $movesource -exclude $exclude | Move-Item -Dest $movedest
        Get-ChildItem -Path  $movesource -Exclude "Documents" | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} |Remove-Item -Recurse -force 
        Write-Host Documents being moved for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Yellow


        }
        else
        {
        Write-Host Documents already moved for $($userhome)
        }

    }
    else
    {
    # Create the Autorecovery folder and set hidden attribute
    Get-Item -path $movesource | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$movesource\Documents\Autorecovery" | %{$_.Attributes="hidden"}
    Write-Host Autorecovery folder being created for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Green

       # Check if Autorecovery folder exists 
       If (Test-Path $autodest)
       {
       Write-Host Autorecovery folder now exists for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Magenta

            # Move Documents to new location
            If (Test-Path $testpath)
            {
            Get-Childitem -path $movesource -exclude $exclude | Move-Item -Dest $movedest
            Get-ChildItem -Path  $movesource -Exclude "Documents" | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} |Remove-Item -Recurse -force 
            Write-Host Documents being moved for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Yellow


            }
            else
            {
            Write-Host Documents already moved for $($userhome)
            }
       }
       else
       {
       Write-Host ERROR Autorecovery folder still does not exist for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Red
       }

    }
}
else
{
Write-Host ERROR Documents folder still does not exist for $($userhome) -ForegroundColor Red
}
}
}
```